# The difference between "in seiner am 12.10.2014 stattgefundenen Sitzung" and "in seiner stattgefundenen Sitzung vom 12.10.2014"?

Tags: sentence-structure

What's the difference between these three sentences?

Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner am 12.10.2014 stattgefundenen Sitzung...

Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner stattgefundenen Sitzung vom 12.10.2014...

Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner  stattgefundenen Sitzung am 12.10.2014...

Comment: There wouldn't be a difference if these sentences wouldn't have something in common: all three are wrong. *... in seiner am ... stattgefunden habenden Stizung* would be correct.

Comment: @Olafant The construction you find correct is rarely used; most speakers seem to avoid it.

Comment: What's the matter of knowing the exact difference? All 3 make sense and are technically correct.

Comment: Wenn eine Sitzung an einem konkreten Datum in der Vergangenheit im Satz genannt wird, ist "stattgefunden" bereits impliziert. Wenn der Ausschuss etwas auf seiner nicht stattgefunden Sitzung beschloss, müsste das ein seltsames Gremium sein.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nehmen wir an, dass die Sitzung möglicherweise über **mehrere Tage** ging (etwa bis spät in die Nacht). Dann ergeben sich Unterschiede.

> Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner am 12.10.2014 stattgefundenen Sitzung...

Impliziert, dass die Sitzung nur am 12.10.2014 stattfand und an keinem anderen Tag.

> Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner stattgefundenen Sitzung vom 12.10.2014...

Für mich heißt das:

1. Die Sitzung dauert nicht mehr an, sondern ist abgeschlossen.
2. Die Sitzung begann am 12.10.2014.
3. Der Beschluss kann am 12.10.2014, aber auch an einem späteren Tag derselben Sitzung gefasst worden sein.

> Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner stattgefundenen Sitzung am 12.10.2014...

Hier:

1. Die Sitzung dauert nicht mehr an, sondern ist abgeschlossen.
2. Der Beschluss wurde am 12.10.2014 gefasst.
3. Vielleicht begann die Sitzung am 12.10.2014, vielleicht an einem früheren Tag.

Answer (score 0):

All three sentences are grammatically incorrect as the verb "stattfinden" isn't transitive. 
However that kind of misuse of participles is common and accepted in legal and bureaucratic style.

In the first sentence "stattgefunden" appears strictly redundant. It is exactly equivalent to the grammatically correct:

> Der Ausschuss beschloss in seiner Sitzung vom/am 12.10.2014 ...

In the second and third sentences "stattgefunden" is a separate attribute to "Sitzung" which stresses the fact that the meeting in question has indeed taken place, probably in contrast to another which was cancelled.

The difference between "vom" and "am" is marginal.